Incorrect syntax near '00'. using sql
string ssql2 = 

    @"INSERT INTO trauditmain
        (docid,
         temporarydocno,
         temporarydocdate,
         referanceno,
         referencedate,
         permanentdocno,
         permanentdocdate,
         operationlog,
         entrydate,
         userid)
VALUES      (" + txtdocid.text + ",
         " + txttemporarydocno.text + ",
         " + dtptemporarydocdate.value.tostring() + ",
         " + txtreferanceno.text + ",
         '" + dtpReferanceDate.Value.ToString() + "',
         '" + txtPermanentDocNo.Text + "',
         '" + dtpPermanentDocDate.Value.ToString() + "',
'" + " Record Inserted By " + Variables.User + " on " + 
DateTime.Now + "',
'" + DateTime.Now.Date + "',
" + variables.userid + ")";


Wherever you're learning from, please stop using it. Building SQL by concatenating strings is both highly error prone and insecure. There's no reason to be doing it this century. You need to learn to use parameters, and if the source you're learning from doesn't cover those, it's irreparably faulty.

Hopefully never ever uses something as 'drop database' or 'drop table' as name or reference when you using this code.

You should be using Parameterized Query.  This has two advantages:

It will solve you problem, as you don't need to worry about quotes
More importantly, it will protect you against SQL injection.

string ssql2 = @"
    INSERT INTO trauditmain
        (docid, 
         temporarydocno,
         temporarydocdate,
         referanceno,
         referencedate,
         permanentdocno,
         permanentdocdate,
         operationlog,
         entrydate,
         userid)
    VALUES
        (@docid,
         @temporarydocno,
         @temporarydocdate,
         @referanceno,
         @referencedate,
         @permanentdocno,
         @permanentdocdate,
         @operationlog,
         @entrydate,
         @userid)";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ssql2, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@docid", txtdocid.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@temporarydocno", txttemporarydocno.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@temporarydocdate", dtpTemporaryDocDate.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referanceno", txtReferanceNo.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referencedate", dtpReferanceDate.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@permanentdocno", txtPermanentDocNo.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@permanentdocdate", dtpPermanentDocDate.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operationlog", $"Record Inserted By {Variables.User} on {DateTime.Now}");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@entrydate", DateTime.Now.Date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", Variables.UserId);

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}


in newer c# you can use a simpler using syntax so you can avoid the { } nesting

Use SqlCommand to build SQL command instead of writing long string query.
Try below,
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString")) 
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) 
    { 
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO trauditmain(docid, temporarydocno, temporarydocdate) 
                            VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)";  

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", txtdocid.text);  
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", txttemporarydocno.text);  
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", dtptemporarydocdate.value.tostring());  

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            MessgeBox.Show(e.Message.ToString(), "Error Message");
        }

    } 
}

 Note: To make it more clear, I just added three parameters. You can add the remaining parameters.

An option is to use NuGet package Dapper. See examples here.
Benefits for using Dapper, no SqlCommand is needed, just a connection which when needed opens and closes the connection. The SQL statement can be, as shown below be inserted directly into the Execute method or another possibility is using a stored procedure down the road.
In the following code, Audit class has properties that match columns in the insert statement. Dapper created parameters for the value part of the insert statement.
public class Audit
{
    // add properties to use for various data operations
}

Regarding the SQL statement, this is done as a raw string literal, if your version of the .NET Framework does not support raw string literals, use verbatim string as done in @jason.kaisersmith answer.
Side note, you might consider giving entrydate a default value e.g. GETDATE() if the column is to identify when the record was added.
public static bool AddAudit(Audit audit)
{
    using SqlConnection cn = new("TODO");
    // Execute returns the number of rows affected, in this case we expect 1
    return cn.Execute(
        """
            INSERT INTO trauditmain
                (
                     docid, 
                     temporarydocno,
                     temporarydocdate,
                     referanceno,
                     referencedate,
                     permanentdocno,
                     permanentdocdate,
                     operationlog,
                     entrydate,
                     userid
                 )
            VALUES
                (
                     @docid,
                     @temporarydocno,
                     @temporarydocdate,
                     @referanceno,
                     @referencedate,
                     @permanentdocno,
                     @permanentdocdate,
                     @operationlog,
                     @entrydate,
                     @userid
                 )
            """, audit) == 1;
}

